# Stop 0x7b after replacing motherboard in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod

On a system where the CPU and motherboard had to be changed, the Windows 7 installation doesn't boot up. We have tried changing AHCI to IDE and vice versa, but to no avail. When I Disable Automatic Restart on System Failure, it's a 0x7b error.

I have tried Microsoft's fix of disabling the Msahci service, but that didn't work. I also tried going a step further and disabling all the IDE drivers in the registry (setting START=0) and enabling all AHCI drivers (START=3), and ensuring the BIOS is set to AHCI storage. Any other ideas?

Comment: What's the motherboard?

Comment: identical motherboard?

Comment: It was an HP motherboard, I replaced it with an Asus P7Q57-M DO

Comment: @Moab That's what I had to do. Make it an answer and I'll mark it for you

Comment: @Luke It is done

Comment: START=0 enables the driver, START=4 disables it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall W7, hardware is too different.

Comment: -1 I was able to move Windows from an old Asus TUSL2-C to a Dell Optiplex 755. The trick is to [fake installing drivers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822052). Of course, things may have changed since Win2k.

Comment: I disagee, this move could easily be done. All you have to do is manually hack the boot driver so it finds the hard drive and plug-and-play will do the rest. Then just delete the old drivers. (Tools like Acronis Backup and Recovery can do the boot driver, but it can be done manually as well.)

Comment: So easy you could not post the details in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be a long shot, but boot from the Win7 disc and go the recovery console. It'd be interesting to see if the automated startup recovery wizard can detect the need to change drivers and do it for you.